# Why does Debugging Native code using GDB of a JAR application hangs Ubuntu UI (X11 Process) when breakpoint is hit?

Tags: java, c, gdb, x11, freeze

My project is basically a Communication client like lync which is developed in JAVA for front end (GUI) and uses platform specific native (C or C++) code for running services.

Now, on Linux, (Ubuntu 12.04), once the JAR application is invoked, it loads all the native code shared libraries and the UI thread starts executing. Any action done in the UI will throw an event to the native code which is in C. So currently i need to debug a crash in a C/C++ user library which is triggered when i do something in a UI drop down.

I am using GDB, to attach to the PID of the process , (sudo gdb -p ), all the symbols are loaded and i am able to set a breakpoint to a function say A() in the library.After continue command in GDB, i select the instance from UI Dropdown and breakpoint is hit at Function A(). At this moment, my ubuntu machine hangs and no keyboard interrupts are working. I am only able to move my mouse pointer but cannot click on anything.

However, to verify that kernel is not down, i can ping the machine and even SSH is possible. Once the same GDB is invoked by SSH the above problem is not encountered. May anyone please help me out here as to why UI or X11 process hangs during the above scenario.

PS: Yes there are lot of threads running, it might be a thread deadlock situation but it does not happen when GDB is invoked by SSH terminal.

Thanks and Regards,
Indra

Comment: Does this help? [Hangs when debugging popup menus and similar components on X11](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/tsg/TSG-Desktop/html/awt.html#gdadua)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why UI or X11 process hangs during the above scenario

As Mark Plotnick correctly pointed out, the X11 process does *not* hang. Rather, it grabs the keybard (all keyboard events are dispatched to it), and can not release that grab (it is stopped by GDB before it reaches the release point).

There are two common solutions:

1. ask the application to [not do the keyboard grab](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/webnotes/tsg/TSG-Desktop/html/awt.html#gdadua) (as Mark said), or
2. debug the application from a separate machine (this can even be done on single physical machine: just run the application inside a VM).

P.S. Why do application menues grab keyboard? Because hitting `Esc` usually dismisses the menu, and they want to see that `Esc` regardless of whether the application has input focus or not).

Comment: Thank you so much. This information is beneficial in understanding things going behind user application.